# How do you begin working with Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: android, sql, cloud

I have working Android App and nothing else!  I have tried searching for help via Google, but they keep talking about an option in Android Studio under Tools -> Google Cloud ->  Create App Engine Backend.

I don't have that option available in my Android Studio.

Could anyone give me either a link or a few steps to get this set up?  I have a project in Google Cloud and have a SQL database setup there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you to give a brief overview on the google cloud endpoints

http://rominirani.com/2014/01/16/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-3/